# wxPython - Manually resizing panels with unexpected/undesired visual results

Tags: wxpython

I'm working on my own alternative for the wx.Sizer class which allows me to basically treat the interface like a table (or more accurately, a series of nested tables).

Basically, there are two parts to it-- my names for them make more sense in the context of the problem, so we'll just call them sections and cells.

A section is basically a column OR a row, depending on how it is oriented, and the cells are the items in said column or row.  It has its own definitions for margins, alignment, and spacing between cells, and rules for how the cells are to be sized.  A section can be a frame, a panel, or just a logical construct.  A cell can itself be a a section, with its own orientation, alignment, margins, and spacing, or just a panel, button, etc.  A cell can override the sizing or the alignment of the section.

Functionally it goes like this:

1. Frame resizes, wx.EVT_SIZE triggers the adjust() function.
2. At the frame level, "adjust" pulls GetClientSize() and does the math using those numbers.
3. adjust() uses the size to determine the size and placement of its cells, then calls adjust() on those cells, providing the size and position for those cells to be.
4. if the cell is a panel, adjust() will resize and reposition the panel accordingly.
5. If the cell is also a section, adjust() will repeat step 3, using the provided numbers, and invoking adjust() on its own cells.

And it works.  Well, mostly.  For example:

[image: a screenshot]

The above consists of:

- a horizontally aligned section/frame (black background)
- a vertically aligned section/panel (grey) with three panel/cells (blue, white, and red)
- a vertically aligned section/panel (grey) with four panel/cells (blue, white, white, and red)

And everything is exactly where and how I want it.  And if I resize it, everything will stay exactly how and where I want it.

Except.
Sometimes I get a weird thing.

[image: another screenshot, this one not so perfect]

That little white bar in the blue bar should NOT be there.  (The grey line at the top of column A is unwanted, but I know why it's there.)

It doesn't seem to happen consistently, and it only happens when increasing the size, usually rapidly.  This includes (sometimes) maximizing the window.  Unfortunately, once it happens, the error remains when it is resized until it's sized small enough that the part with the glitch goes away.

That is just the example I got for that screenshot-- sometimes it's a bar, sometimes it's lines. (The lines are usually white (assuming from the panel) but ocassionally black (frame background).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

The adjust() function now calls Refresh() on the panels it's adjusting.  (This marking the first time Refresh() has helped me with anything I've tried it on.)